# Repository state Merging in JGit

Tags: jgit

I am trying to resolve the merge conflicts programmatically, i.e force merge.
After resolving merge conflicts, if i try to commit i get the below exception:

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.WrongRepositoryStateException: Cannot commit into a repository with state: MERGING.

How do I change the repository status or am I missing something.
Code snippet:

```java
if((RepositoryState.SAFE == pullCommand.getRepository().getRepositoryState())) {
  PullResult result = pullCommand.call();
  if(MergeStatus.CONFLICTING == result.getMergeResult().getMergeStatus()){

     mgCmd = git.merge();
     mgCmd.include(repo.getRef("refs/remotes/origin/development"));
     mgCmd.setStrategy(MergeStrategy.OURS);
     mgCmd.setCommit(true);
     res = mgCmd.call(); 
     System.out.println("Failing Path ==="+res.getFailingPaths());
     pullCommand.getRepository().resolve("C:\\CODE\\thin\\thinclient\\.git");
     if(res.getMergeStatus().equals(MergeResult.MergeStatus.CONFLICTING)){
       System.out.println("Merge status=========+++"+res.getMergeStatus());
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MergeCommand` is not meant to resolve merge conflicts. The contrary is true, it will cause merge conflicts if the included ref(s) cannot be merged without conflicts.

The `PullCommand` is a *composite command* that first fetches commits from upstream and then tries to merge them using the `MergeCommand`.

In order to programmatically resolve merge conflicts, you need to change files in the local work directory accordingly, add them to the index, and then issue a *merge commit*.

Information about conflicting files can be found in `pullResult.getMergeResult()`. A *merge commit* can be created with the regular `CommitCommand`.

Comment: thanks
But do you mean that i need to manually change the files in the local working directory.
If there are merge conflicts i want only the local changes in the file. And I am trying to achieve this programmatically. I have just started exploring jgit api. Could you help me know how this can be achieved.. Thanks

Comment: If the MergeStrategy `ÒURS` is sufficient for your use case, you need to tell the PullCommand to use that strategy (i.e. `pullCommand.setStrategy( OURS )`. Did you try that?

Comment: Hi, I tried pullCommand.setStrategy( OURS ). It is working as expected. Thanks a lot...:)